# Bean Validations not using proper basename to find resource bundles despite custom messageSource bean

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, bean-validation

I added a bean (which *is* being instantiated and which is used when I `@Autowire` it into my classes. But it's not used by bean validation to get the proper messages.

The bean:

```
@Bean
public MessageSource messageSource()
{
    //Create our message source (so we can set directories to use)
    ResourceBundleMessageSource messageSource = new ResourceBundleMessageSource();

    //Add all our basenames (ours and the custom ones)
    messageSource.setBasenames(
        "/appbundles/ValidationMessages"
    );

    return messageSource;
}
```

In my resources directory, I have:

```
/resources
    /appbundles
        ValidationMessages_en_US.properties
```

When I do it that way, it does *not* use the messages in that properties directory. If, instead, I move the properties file out to the root of "/resources" then it *does* work.

How can I make bean validation use the proper basename?

Comment: have you tried specifying the full path? resources/appbundles/ValidationMessages_en_US.properties? Under the root, it's automatically being taken as a properties container!
And also please rectify the parameter you set in the setBasenames method.

Comment: @sbs How would that work? In a jar, does it still have the resources directory? I thought that wasn't put into the jar?